trying filter some items in parsehup
I am using parsehup for webscrabing and I am trying to collest players names in wotreplays website .simply I open teamscore screen and collecting all names of players that played in match . but some players in clans and they clan name is writing with player name (ex: rez720 [REL-2]) (clan names is in [ ] ).
I am searching palyers in https://tanks.gg/ to find their most played 25 tanks to crate a data set . but in tanks.gg you have to search only players names not with klan names . so how I remove clan names while parsehup Extracting palyers names.
link of WoTReplays : http://wotreplays.eu/site/6754329#teams
tanks gg: https://tanks.gg/
I tried if comment but I think it is not right tool.
